Ci diamo del tu?
Mi sembra comune darsi del tu nelle comunita' online, ma vorrei che formalizzassimo questa convenzione qui su meta in caso dei nuovi utenti abbiano dubbi o abbiamo ospiti illustri come ad esemprio professori universitari o noti esperti.
In questa comunita' si usa sempre la forma del "tu"?

Approvo, in pieno.
Non vedo motivi di aggiungere barriere formali, in fondo siamo su Internet.


Nello specifico, tutti i siti SE sono caratterizzati da un tono molto informale

In un forum di lingua italiana che ho guardato di tanto in tanto, il tono con il ‘lei’ mi pareva molto fasullo. O forse era addirittura un modo di ritenersi superiori.
Propendo decisamente per il ‘tu’ (ma ai miei studenti do rigorosamente del ‘lei‘).

Beh, per tutte le domande fatte in inglese il problema non si pone :-)
(per il resto, io sono abituato a usare il "tu" ma è trent'anni che scrivo in rete, e ai tempi eravamo davvero in pochi. Poi se qualcuno vuole il lei rispondo col lei)
